# Firebase switch header option with onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm sorry if my question has already asked. 
I am a beginner on react and I really want to learn how to do this and understand.
I use Firebase on my React.JS project and i want switch a part of header when the user has connected or not.

I think using the conditional-rendering but on the firebase function after the (if) does not allow me to do setState().. or i have an error

So I would be very happy if we could help me or give me a track of where to look for the answers !

```
class Header extends Component {

state={
  connected: null
}

render(){

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {


    } else {


    }
  });

  return (


<div className="backgroundheader">

<div className="liensheader">
  <a href="/" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Home</a>
  <a href="/event" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Manifestations</a>
  <a href="/commerces" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Commerces</a>
  <a href="/tips" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Tips</a>
</div>

{/* options header when the user is disconnect */}
{/* <Deader /> */}

{/* options header when the user is connected */}
{/* <Ceader /> */}

</div>
  );
  }
};
export default Header;
```

Thank's you and sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` fires asynchronously, so you can't directly use it inside your `render` method. Whenever you have a situation like this, the solution is to put the asynchronous value into the state, and then use the state in the `render` method.

So something like:

```
class Header extends Component {
  state={
    connected: null
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      setState({ user: user });
    });    
  }
  render(){
    return (
<div className="backgroundheader">

<div className="liensheader">
  <a href="/" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Home</a>
  <a href="/event" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Manifestations</a>
  <a href="/commerces" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Commerces</a>
  <a href="/tips" className="lili" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Tips</a>
</div>
{ user ? <Deader /> : <Ceader /> }
</div>
  );
  }
};
export default Header;
```

Also see:

- [Firebase storage: download images to and put to img src in React map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190939/firebase-storage-download-images-to-and-put-to-img-src-in-react-map/61192087#61192087). The same problem of asynchronously loaded data, but then with getting the download URL of images in Cloud Storage.
- [How to update Firebase data to the React application in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871401/how-to-update-firebase-data-to-the-react-application-in-realtime/59871491#59871491). This highlights the same problem of asynchronously loaded data, but now with getting JSON data from the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I applied all of this to my code and it works! I will take this opportunity to better understand how it works and to look at the links you sent me. Thanks again, have a nice day!